# This robot has a joint named "wheel_right_joint" which is not in the gazebo model

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone help?

```
<transmission name="tran_${number}">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel_right_joint" type="revolute">
      <insert_block name="origin" />
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-1e+16" upper="1e+16" velocity="3.5"/>
      <axis xyz="-1 0 0" />
      <joint_properties damping="0" friction="0.0" />
      <parent link="base_link" />
      <child link="${name}_link" />
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
  <actuator name="left_wheel_actuator">
  <mechanicalReduction>7</mechanicalReduction>
  <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22084/this-robot-has-a-joint-named-%22wheel_right_joint%22-which-is-not-in-the-gazebo-model./) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8437/pmuthu2s/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Joint tag does not belong inside the transmission tag.

You define your joints in model tags. Then you pass the transmission tags only the name of the joint.

```
<joint name="wheel_right_joint" type="revolute">
      <insert_block name="origin" />
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-1e+16" upper="1e+16" velocity="3.5"/>
      <axis xyz="-1 0 0" />
      <joint_properties damping="0" friction="0.0" />
      <parent link="base_link" />
      <child link="${name}_link" />
</joint>

<transmission name="tran_${number}">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel_right_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="left_wheel_actuator">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>7</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1